# Shortcode Attribute Containing Bracket Issue

Tags: wordpress

The [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) states that you can't have square brackets in your attribute. Thus, the following would not work:

```
[tag attribute="[Some value]"]
```

In my case, the square bracket is required. What would be the best solution of getting around this problem? I've already tried escaping the content in my shortcode function, but had no luck.

I am using WordPress 3.3.1.

Comment: I also need this as my attributes contain filenames, which often have square brackets in them (especially from Macs).

Is there a way to amend the regex so it doesn't close the shorttag if the ] character is after one speechmark and before a second, i.e. within "]"?

Answer (score 1):

Use some other special character in your shortcode and replace it square brackets in your shortcode function. - Since this is not what you want, here's an alternative.

This seems to be the only thing that I can think of that will work in your case, instead of relying on the Shortcode API, you can use "`apply_filters`" on the content, and then use `preg_replace` to write your own shortcode processing function.

Comment: That solution is not ideal, unfortunately. It requires that the user remembers a special character translates into a bracket, which is asking too much. I'd rather actually solve the problem than devolve my code into workarounds. Thanks for suggesting though.

Comment: I have edited my answer to something that should help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If the brackets appear as part of the HTML generated try to use `&#...;` or as part of an URL use `%...` .

Otherwise, if it concerns your own shortcode, just replace some other character, e.g. `{}` by `[]`, inside the code of the shortcode.

If it's not your own shortcode, you might modify the plugin / core. I'd write a wrapper code in order not to break updates.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, all attempts at escaping the bracket are futile. If anything, it looks like I would need to edit the core. I suppose my question is, then, seeking advice from someone who knows the core well on how to do this.

Comment: I'd not modify the core itself, since it will break with every update. Instead try to write your own shortcode, e.g. as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

We store json in shortcode attributes. We decided to use base64_encode to hide square brackets, but we faced some problems:

- Themecheck complains about base64 functions
- When you want to make some replace in database, for e.g. to replace all old site urls with new site url, the regex can't see what's inside a base64 encoded string

---

There is another solution, using htmlentities

```
function encode($str) {
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    // http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php
    $special = array(
        '[' => '&#91;',
        ']' => '&#93;',
    );
    $str = str_replace(array_keys($special), array_values($special), $str);

    return $str;
}

function decode($str) {
    return html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

$original = '[1,2,3,"&",{a:1,b:2,"c":"Результат"}]';
$encoded  = encode($original);
$decoded  = decode($encoded);

echo "Original:\t", $original, PHP_EOL;
echo "Shortcode:\t", '[hi abc="'. $encoded .'"]', PHP_EOL;
echo "Decoded:\t", $decoded, PHP_EOL;
echo "Equal:\t\t", ($original === $decoded) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

Output

```
Original:   [1,2,3,"&",{a:1,b:2,"c":"Результат"}]
Shortcode:  [hi abc="&#91;1,2,3,&quot;&amp;&quot;,{a:1,b:2,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;Результат&quot;}&#93;"]
Decoded:    [1,2,3,"&",{a:1,b:2,"c":"Результат"}]
Equal:      YES
```

http://ideone.com/fNiOkD